# SNMP in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, snmp

i've search google, php manual, github, and of course stackoverflow, founded many many ways, tried some, but none of them worked.

So what i want to ask is, how to use php SNMP in laravel? for now i'm using [nelisys/snmp](https://github.com/nelisys/snmp) library but its not working, the return value was always array(0){ } , even after using the example code. i installed the source code using composer on my laravel, and there were no errors at all. feels so hopeless as any links i found on google were so outdated. here is my code for now:

```
use Nelisys\Snmp;    
$snmp = new Snmp($vd->ip, 'my_community');
if(!is_null($snmp) && $oid){
    $snmp_data = $snmp->get($oid);
}
```

when i var_dump the $snmp , it printed this:

```
object(Nelisys\Snmp)#2434 (5) {
  ["hostname":protected]=>
  string(10) "xx.xx.xx.xx"
  ["community":protected]=>
  string(7) "my_community"
  ["version":protected]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["output_options":protected]=>
  string(6) "0efnqt"
  ["snmpget_max_oids":protected]=>
  int(10)
}
```

can someone help me ? thank you very much.

**UPDATES**:

I tried to make sure that the net-snmp and net-snmp-utils were installed and configured successfully, by following [this](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25949&actp=search) tutorial, yet still, not working like i expected. what should i do now?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Did you install the underlying `net-snmp-utils`?

Comment: @codedge windows 8.1, no i didn't how to install it? i used xampp for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [nelisys/snmp](https://github.com/nelisys/snmp) package clearly says

```
Requires: net-snmp-utils
```

You should should use a Linux derivate, as suggested RedHat and install the `net-snmp-util`. Then you should be able to get the PHP stuff up an running.

For Windows it might be, that http://www.net-snmp.org/download.html is the same ... but I am not sure - better use Linux.